# Package pgf error overleaf

Tags: errors, amsmath

I don't understand why I have this error can you help me?

```tex
\documentclass[mathtools,amsmath,frenchb,12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings,amssymb,babel,tikz,tkz-tab,fontenc,fancyhdr,mathrsfs,amsmath}


\title{TP3-MPE4}
\author{Andréa Madrid}
\date{\today}

\graphicspath{ {./ressources/} }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Etude complète de $C_{1}$}

\begin{cases}
    $x(t) = 2sin(t) + cos(t)$ \\
    $y(t) = sin^3(t) + 2cos^3(t)$
\end{cases}\\

\subsection{Domaine de définition}
La fonction est définie sur $\mathbb{R}$

$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

\subsection{Dérivée}

\begin{cases}
    $x'(t) = 2cos(t) - sin(t)$ \\
    $y'(t) = 3cos(t)sin^2(t) - 6sin(t)cos^2(t)$
\end{cases}

\subsection{Etude de dérivée}
\subsubsection{$x'(t)$}
$x'(t) = 0$ \\
$2cos(t) - sin(t) = 0$ \\
$2cos(t) = sin(t)$ \\
$\frac{1}{2}\frac{sin(t)}{sin(t)} = 0$ \\
$\frac{1}{2}tan(t) = 0$ \\
$ S = {-2.03, 1.10}$\\
\subsubsection{$y'(t)$}
$x'(t) = 0$ \\
$3cos(t)sin^2(t) - 6sin(t)cos^2(t) = 0$ \\
$ S = {-\pi,-2.03, -\frac{\pi}{2}, 0, 1.10, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi}$\\
\subsection{Tableau de variation}
\resizebox{400}{200}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit{$t$/1,$x'(t)$/2, $x(t)$/2, $y'(t)$/3, $y(t)$/4,$-2,03$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $0$, $1,10$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,0,,,,+,,,,0,,-,,}
        \tkzTabVar{/$-1$,-/$2,24$,,,R/,R/,+/$2,24$,R/,-/$-1$}
        \tkzTabLine{0,+,0,-,0,,+,0,-,,0,+,0,-,0}
        \tkzTabVar{-/$-2$,+$-0,89$,-/$-1$,+/$2$,-/$0,89$,+/$1$,-/$2$}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\section{Etude complète de $C_{2}$}
$C_{2} <=> r(\theta) = 1+2cos(\frac{3\theta}{2})$

\subsection{Domaine de définition}
La fonction est définie sur $\mathbb{R}$

$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

\subsection{Dérivée}
$C'_{2}$

$r'(\theta) = -3sin(\frac{3\theta}{2})$

\subsection{Etude de dérivée}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. You do not write what error you get.

Comment: I removed the tikz and overleaf tags as your question is not related to either.

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to overleaf the error is

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.17 \begin{cases}
                  
?
```

But `cases` is for a brace set of clauses in a definition, here I think you want `align`

as `cases` is a math environment (like `array`) so should be inside a display math environment such as `\[...\]` ad should not have `$` within it.

also always use `\sin` not `sin`  here is the start of your document

```
\documentclass[mathtools,amsmath,frenchb,12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings,amssymb,babel,tikz,tkz-tab,fontenc,fancyhdr,mathrsfs,amsmath}


\title{TP3-MPE4}
\author{Andréa Madrid}
\date{\today}

\graphicspath{ {./ressources/} }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Etude complète de $C_{1}$}


\begin{align*}
    x(t) &= 2\sin(t) + \cos(t) \\
    y(t) &= \sin^3(t) + 2\cos^3(t)
\end{align*}


\subsection{Domaine de définition}
La fonction est définie sur $\mathbb{R}$
\[f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\]

\subsection{Dérivée}

\begin{align*}
    x'(t) &= 2\cos(t) - \sin(t) \\
    y'(t) &= 3\cos(t)\sin^2(t) - 6\sin(t)\cos^2(t)
\end{align*}

\subsection{Etude de dérivée}
\subsubsection{$x'(t)$}
\begin{align*}
x'(t) &= 0 \\
2\cos(t) - \sin(t) &= 0 \\
2\cos(t) &= \sin(t) \\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin(t)}{\sin(t)} &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}\tan(t) &= 0 \\
 S &= \{-2.03, 1.10\}
\end{align*}
\subsubsection{$y'(t)$}
\begin{align*}
x'(t) &= 0 \\
3\cos(t)\sin^2(t) - 6\sin(t)\cos^2(t) &= 0 \\
 S &= \{-\pi,-2.03, -\frac{\pi}{2}, 0, 1.10, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is related to tikz, whithout the table I created, the code is working. I will try your code and send you a feedback. Thank you for helping me

Comment: My problem is this : \subsection{Tableau de variation}
\resizebox{400}{200}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit{$t$/1,$x'(t)$/2, $x(t)$/2, $y'(t)$/3, $y(t)$/4,$-2,03$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $0$, $1,10$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,0,,,,+,,,,0,,-,,}
        \tkzTabVar{/$-1$,-/$2,24$,,,R/,R/,+/$2,24$,R/,-/$-1$}
        \tkzTabLine{0,+,0,-,0,,+,0,-,,0,+,0,-,0}
        \tkzTabVar{-/$-2$,+$-0,89$,-/$-1$,+/$2$,-/$0,89$,+/$1$,-/$2$}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

Comment: @AndréaMadrid your example gave tex errors before it reached that so I did not even consider that part of the document.

Comment: Ok I understand. I changed my code with your correction

Comment: @AndréaMadrid You should probably ask a new question asking about that, without all the unrelated errors and unrelated packages

Comment: Sure, i will delete this question and ask another one